# make yolo on macbook pro / "cuda_runtime.h"

Tags: makefile, terminal, yolo

I want to use YOLOV3 on my MacBook Pro Retina (I have there a NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M) and train it with some of my own pictures.

The "make"-command in terminal says:include/darknet.h:11:14: fatal error: 'cuda_runtime.h' file not found

So I downloaded everything, installed:
- CUDA Driver Version: 418.163 (GPU Driver Version: 355.11.10.50.10.103)

Here is the full error, shown in the mac terminal:

```
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./src/gemm.c -o obj/gemm.o
In file included from ./src/gemm.c:2:
In file included from src/utils.h:5:
include/darknet.h:11:14: fatal error: 'cuda_runtime.h' file not found
    #include "cuda_runtime.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

1 error generated.

Comment: At first glance, it appears that `coda_runtime.h` is either missing entirely, or not in your bundle target.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I thought to install Yolo I just have to download a fitting Coda-Driver and that's it. But I used this instructions to solve it:
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a great place to start is listening to what the error message is telling you! This one appears to be accurate - that `cuda_runtime.h` is missing from your filesystem, or the bundle target.

As you discovered, the [Cuda docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html) have the installation instructions you need to make sure the driver is installed correctly.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. Installing Cuda on a MacBook really can be an adventure! But looks like I managed to do it. Thanks again and good night :)